# Perl array attribute inside an object

Tags: perl

Tried to write a perl module with OOP, but it can add an object to an array, when I use Dump method, it will output wrong data like this. Where is my error ?

Thanks

```
bless( {
                 '_name' => 'CUSIP',
                 '_validation_array' => [],
                 '_seq' => '1'
               }, 'Field' );
```

source code:

```
 package Field;

    sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
        _name => shift,
        _seq => shift,
        _validation_array => [ @_ ],
    };

    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
};

sub pushValidation(){
    my $validation = shift;   
    push(@{$self->{_validation_array}}, $validation);     
};

sub dump(){
    foreach my $validation (@{$self->{_validation_array} })   {
        #print Dumper($validation);#will work, 
        print $validation->{name}; #error, Use of uninitialized value
    }
}        
    1;
```

This is the way I call this method :

```
my $validationObj = new Validation($validation->{name}, $validation->{seq});
$field->pushValidation($validationObj);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see several problems here, but the most serious one is here:

```
sub pushValidation() {
    my $validation = shift;   
    push(@{$self->{_validation_array}}, $validation);     
};
```

This function is expecting a `$self` argument, but isn't shifting it from the arguments. **You need to add `use strict;` at the top of your Perl file.** If it had been enabled, the issue would have been immediately obvious:

```
Global symbol "$self" requires explicit package name at <filename> line <line>.
```

Same thing goes for the `dump()` function. (By the way, `dump` is a bad method name, as there is an (obscure) Perl builtin function with the same name. But that's not a huge issue.)

Comment: correct, I put the 'use strict', I see this error. how to fix it ?

Comment: You need to shift out `$self` as the first argument to the function - e.g, add `my $self = shift;` before the `$validation` argument. Alternatively, unpack both at one: `my ($self, $validation) = @_;`.

Comment: I made this change, inside the dump, use print $validation->{name}; still get error, "Use of uninitialized value in print"

Comment: As I believe someone else pointed out in a comment, some of your attribute references have leading underscores (e.g, `$self->{_name}`) and some don't (`$self->{name}`). Either one will work, but you need to be consistent.